# Configure GA4 for a website with multiple locations

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I am working on an eCommerce project for a company that will have a single site/domain but users are able to select their active location while shopping. This is a pretty common pattern for many sites where the user can order online or pickup in store.

I am trying to figure out the best configuration for GA4 to track both overall site traffic while also being able to traffic metrics for each individual location. I did find a resource here but it doesn't quite make sense. The summary of requirements are:

1. Ability to track GA4 metrics for the overall site
2. Ability to track GA4 metrics for each individual location (based on the location selected by a user)
3. Each individual location should be able to have access to view their own GA4 metrics.

The only solution I can think of that checks all 3 boxes is setting up a property for all analytics, as well as an individual property for each location and then send tracking events to both but this seems like bad practice. I would appreciate any insight or recommendations others might have for this scenario.

Comment: Can you just send the locations a report? You could probably create separate dashboards and share them individually; that gives them the data they need without having to make that many properties.